# How to manually read JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, ipad

Can someone give me advice on reading JSON? I have an RSS feed in JSON, but am not sure how to decipher it so I can use it in code.  In the past I would parse JSON, but I would have an API from the web guys that said "the keyword albums is a list of objects". So then I would parse the JSON and shove the "albums" into an NSArray. I'm using SBJSON for iOS if it matters.

I'm trying to get RSS data from iTunes but I don't see an API document anywhere and am unsure how to properly parse the data.

Here is the link:
[iTunes JSON](http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=25/json)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am just going to get you a little into it, you will have to digg dipper to get more data. This is how you would parse the following JSON:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "author": {
      "name": {
        "label": "iTunes Store"
      },
      "uri": {
        "label": "http://www.apple.com/itunes/"
      }
    },
    "entry": [
      {
        "im:name": {
          "label": "Sexy and I Know It"
        },
        "im:image": [
          {
            "label": "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/037/Music/3c/0c/ba/mzi.levtcsmk.55x55-70.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "55"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/037/Music/3c/0c/ba/mzi.levtcsmk.60x60-50.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "60"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/037/Music/3c/0c/ba/mzi.levtcsmk.170x170-75.jpg",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "170"
            }
          }
        ],
```

Assuming that the above data is stored in a `NSString` called `json`.

Read json data into a `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *data = [json JSONValue];
```

Get the `NSDictionary` representation of `feed` object

```
NSDictionary *feed = (NSDictionary *) [data objectForKey:@"feed"];
```

Get the `NSDictionary` representation of `author` object

```
NSDictionary *author = (NSDictionary *) [feed objectForKey:@"author"];
```

Get the `NSDictionary` representation of `name` object

```
NSDictionary *name = (NSDictionary *) [author objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Get the `NSString` representation of `label` object

```
NSString *label = (NSString *) [name objectForKey:@"label"];
```

... and so on

Now lets get collection of entry objects

Get the `NSArray` representation of `entry` object

```
NSArray *entry = (NSArray *) [data objectForKey:@"entry"];
```

Lets get an NSArray of Image objects from the entry collection

```
NSArray *images = [[entry objectAtIndex[0]] objectForKey:@"im:image"];
```

Hope that helps you understand the parsing flow.

Comment: This is perfect. I understand completely now!